# How do I change the Plan for my API Connect service in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I have an API Connect service in Bluemix. All working fine. But I now realise I chose the wrong Plan when I implemented it, and I want to change the Plan (from Enterprise 25M to something else).

How do I change the Plan ?

Or, if I can't change the Plan, I guess I could create a new API Connect service with the new Plan. But then how do I save all my APIs and Products and all the other stuff from my original API Connect instance and then import them all into the new one ?

Answer (score 1):

Hugh,

There is currently not a self-service path to changing your API Connect plan. You would need to reach out to Bluemix Support to discuss the options for migrating to a new plan. https://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport

However, if you are interested in exporting your artifacts so you could import them into a new service instance, there is the ability to individually export your Products and APIs. When you are looking at the editor page, you can click the [...] button in the top right corner. From here, you can click [Download]. This will download the full yaml file for your API or Product. Once you have them downloaded, you could reimport them in your new instance by clicking [Add] then [Import API from a file or URL] on the drafts page. You'll be able to upload your yaml file from the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Please open a Bluemix support ticket to change your plan: https://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport

Remember, Stack Overflow is for technical programming questions. You can ask questions about your Bluemix account on [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/).